# When editing an array "in place", why does overwriting the array not work, but overwriting each element does?

Tags: c#

In C#, I have a function that should edit an array (not return new one). Why when I try to set the input variable to a new/update array it doesn't work, but when I loop over the array and change all the values it does? I've been developing for some time and this has always been a thing I've just accepted, but was hoping someone could clear it up for me.

```
public static void RightCircularRotation(int[] input){
  var newList = new List<int>();
  newList.Add (input[input.Length-1]);

    for(var i = 0; i< input.Length-1; i++){
        newList.Add(input[i]);
    }
    // Why doesn't this overwrite the input variable, but the for loop does?
    //input = newList.ToArray();

    for(var i = 0; i< input.Length; i++){
        input[i] = newList.ElementAt(i);
    }
    
}
```

I've tried to overwrite an input array with a new array but setting it to the new array with no luck. However, when I loop through and set each variable it does what I expect. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int[]` is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) and `input` is just a local variable storing that reference, so the first snippet just writes a reference to a new array (the result of `ToArray` call) into the local variable, while the second snippet updates the data stored by the "original" passed reference.

You can use [`ref` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) to make the first snippet work (though I'm not saying you should):

> When used in a method's parameter list, the `ref` keyword indicates that an argument is passed by reference, not by value. The `ref` keyword makes the formal parameter an alias for the argument, which must be a variable. In other words, any operation on the parameter is made on the argument.

```cs
public static void RightCircularRotation(ref int[] input)
{
    var newList = new List<int>();
    newList.Add (input[input.Length-1]);

    for(var i = 0; i< input.Length-1; i++){
        newList.Add(input[i]);
    }
    input = newList.ToArray();
}
```

But this will require updating usages with it too - `RightCircularRotation(ref someArray)`.

P.S.

Actually here is no need to create a new list to perform the task (unless you want to keep the source array immutable), you can use single local variable to keep the "current" moved array item and perform iteration (i.e. store the last element in it and then iterate through array performing swaps between "current" and i-th element of array)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Seems obvious now. Also not sure how I feel about the ref keyword, i guess it can be an antipattern depending on code base? Could one also make an extension method off int[] so that calling input.RotateRight() or something would mutate the array? And to your P.S., I actually was writing it that way but my for loop was probably in the wrong direction and was swapping for already swapped variables, so I think [1,2,3,4,5,6] was giving me [6,1,1,1,1,1] or something. If you find that sort of stuff fun you should give it a shot.

Comment: Oh, and I think just to make the answer complete, calling `input[i]` in the `for` loop works and the actual value is changed because the compiler goes "to" the `input` reference and changes the value inside the actual array that's being referenced.

Comment: @MichaelG yes that is exactly what I have meant by _"while the second snippet updates the data stored by the "original" passed reference"_